# Is <a href="#">link</a> a broken link?

Tags: html, links, validation

When using empty URL fragment links, to send a user to the top of the page (e.g. `<a href="#">return to top</a>`), are these links considered broken or invalid? One of my tools is returning them all as broken links.

Comment: What "tool" is considering them broken?

Comment: A PHP program I use to generate a sitemap.

Comment: @Su': why did you delete my thanks? I was sincere!

Comment: @Nathan I'm sure you were. But the SE sites aren't really discussion forums and it's basically a waste of time and space. [Just ask the question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93989/156275). Show your appreciation by upvoting/accepting answers. Jeff's answer there is the "canonical" one, but see some of the others for different takes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Technically, "#" is a well-defined URL reference that points to the start of the current document, so it is not “broken” in formal sense. It can, however, be regarded as [bad for accessibility](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/www/totop.html), and it is also a common symptom of “fake” links, i.e. `a` elements that are supposed to link to something external but depend on JavaScript. (In the very old days, `<a href="..." onclick="...">` was the only kind of element that supported  the `onclick` attribute, so people wrote the “dummy” `href="#"` attribute, which isn’t really dummy.)

So you can regard this as an incorrect error message, or as a useful warning message that might be a little poorly formulated.

Comment: Do you have a source for # being well-defined and pointing to the start of the document (i.e. a w3c spec)?

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat, it’s specified in Internet-standard STD 66, “Uniform Resource Identifier (URI): Generic Syntax”, clause 4.4. Same-Document Reference, available e.g. at https://tools.ietf.org/html/std66#section-4.4

Comment: Kudos for providing a source, although I don't see anything that specifies `#` on its own refers to the start of the document.

Comment: Well, yes, the standard isn’t too clear about it, but it’s natural to assume that a referenced document is initially positioned at the start. Its predecessor RFC 2396 was more explicit: “4.2. Same-document References.

   A URI reference that does not contain a URI is a reference to the
   current document.  In other words, an empty URI reference within a
   document is interpreted as a reference to the start of that document,
   and a reference containing only a fragment identifier is a reference
   to the identified fragment of that document.”

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it is considered as broken link.

Broken link is a link that points to resources doesn't exist (404 HTTP response).

Comment: Don't hedge this answer with "In my opinion". It's not a matter of opinion, it's a matter of fact (and you are correct).

Comment: @msanford: You're right, I edited my answer.